# AppWidget crashes in onDisabled

Tags: android, widget, android-appwidget

I'm making widget, that will be updated by Intent.ACTION_TIME_TICK.

So I registered reciever (my AppWidgetProvider):

```
private IntentFilter intentFilter = new IntentFilter(Intent.ACTION_TIME_TICK);

@Override
    public void onEnabled(Context context) {
        super.onEnabled(context);
        context.getApplicationContext().registerReceiver(this, intentFilter);   
    }
```

Everything works fine. But when i try to unregister reciever, app crashes:

```
@Override
public void onDisabled(Context context) {   
    context.getApplicationContext().unregisterReceiver(this);  
    super.onDisabled(context);
}
```

It throws

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Receiver not registered:
com.holoware.holoclock.HoloClockWidgetProvider@41a3a3e8
```

Logs:

```
D/AndroidRuntime( 3937): Shutting down VM
W/dalvikvm( 3937): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x4
19e8300)
E/AndroidRuntime( 3937): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
E/AndroidRuntime( 3937): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start receiver co
m.holoware.holoclock.HoloClockWidgetProvider: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException
: Receiver not registered: com.holoware.holoclock.HoloClockWidgetProvider@41d616
20
E/AndroidRuntime( 3937):        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleReceiver(Act
ivityThread.java:2362)
E/AndroidRuntime( 3937):        at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1500(Activi
tyThread.java:142)
E/AndroidRuntime( 3937):        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(Ac
tivityThread.java:1284)
E/AndroidRuntime( 3937):        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.ja
va:99)
E/AndroidRuntime( 3937):        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
E/AndroidRuntime( 3937):        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThrea
d.java:4931)
E/AndroidRuntime( 3937):        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native
Method)
E/AndroidRuntime( 3937):        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:5
11)
E/AndroidRuntime( 3937):        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndA
rgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:791)
E/AndroidRuntime( 3937):        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(Zygot
eInit.java:558)
E/AndroidRuntime( 3937):        at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)

E/AndroidRuntime( 3937): Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Receiver
 not registered: com.holoware.holoclock.HoloClockWidgetProvider@41d61620
E/AndroidRuntime( 3937):        at android.app.LoadedApk.forgetReceiverDispatche
r(LoadedApk.java:654)
E/AndroidRuntime( 3937):        at android.app.ContextImpl.unregisterReceiver(Co
ntextImpl.java:1166)
E/AndroidRuntime( 3937):        at android.content.ContextWrapper.unregisterRece
iver(ContextWrapper.java:378)
E/AndroidRuntime( 3937):        at com.holoware.holoclock.HoloClockWidgetProvide
r.onDisabled(HoloClockWidgetProvider.java:53)
E/AndroidRuntime( 3937):        at android.appwidget.AppWidgetProvider.onReceive
(AppWidgetProvider.java:91)
E/AndroidRuntime( 3937):        at com.holoware.holoclock.HoloClockWidgetProvide
r.onReceive(HoloClockWidgetProvider.java:63)
E/AndroidRuntime( 3937):        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleReceiver(Act
ivityThread.java:2355)
E/AndroidRuntime( 3937):        ... 10 more
```

Comment: E/AndroidRuntime( 3974): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
E/AndroidRuntime( 3974): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start receiver co
m.holoware.holoclock.HoloClockWidgetProvider: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException
: Receiver not registered: com.holoware.holoclock.HoloClockWidgetProvider@41a3ae
70

Comment: please use the edit option on the post and add you logs to your question with code formatting...

Comment: can you provide some more logs.. just want to see if un-register is getting called twice...

Answer (score 0):

make sure that your `onDisabled()` is not getting called twice also check if you are un-registering the the receiver at some other method also...

Try putting un-register code in try catch like following code..

```
@Override
    public void onDisabled(Context context) {       
        try{
                context.getApplicationContext().unregisterReceiver(this);
         } catch(Exception e){}
        super.onDisabled(context);
    }
```

Comment: I'am sure that onDisabled() is called only once. And I'm not using other methods to unregister reciever.

Comment: Already tryed to put try catch. It cathes (as I mentioned in question) `java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Receiver not registered:
com.holoware.holoclock.HoloClockWidgetProvider@41a3a3e8`

Comment: does its still crash your app?

Comment: ok so your app work fine and only concern is the exception.. can you put logs in on disabled method to check how many times it is getting called...

Comment: @Joel:context.getApplicationContext().unregisterReceiver(this);

Comment: are other part of your application working fine other then this exception? are you able to receive the broadcast for TIME_TICK?

Comment: @Praful Everything else works fine. There are no problem with receiving TIME_TICK.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is, `onEnabled()` is called only when the first widget is added. If the widget has already been added and you start your application, `onEnabled()` won't be called. That's why the receiver is not registered and you get an exception unregistering it. I suggest you create your `Intent` this way:

```
    Intent intent = new Intent(context, YourAppWidgetProvider.class);
    intent.setAction(action);
```

Comment: I registered reciever to the ApplicationContext, not to widget context. And  `registerReceiver()` takes only IntentFilter as a parameter.

Comment: 1. Put your widget on your homescreen. 2. Restart the application. 3. Check if onEnabled() has been called. I suggest it's NOT called and that's why your receiver has not been registered. Then you remove the widget, onDisabled() gets called and you try to unregister the receiver which leads to an exception.

Comment: I mean, if you create your intent the way I suggested, you won't need registerReceiver at all, the class name which you put in the constructor's parameter is enough to address your Provider.